# Can we write a script to run some command within each interactive bash shell process?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Is there a way to write a script which can go over all the interactive bash shell processes running on the same computer one by one, and run some command in each interactive bash shell respectively?

- Assume only bash, no zsh etc. but if there are other kinds of shells such as zsh, then all the shells.
- "interactive" because the command I am going to run is to collect some information about interactive usage of a shell, for example running `dirs` or `jobs` and collecting their outputs from all the shells into a single list or  file.
- Two interactive shell processes are deemed different, if `dirs` or `jobs`  gives different outputs in them.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Two interactive shell processes are deemed different, if `dirs` or `jobs`  gives different outputs in them.

Comment: This may be related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/how-to-refresh-all-bash-shells-using-a-command-script and, as such, may be limited to shell initialization (e.g., '/etc/profile', '${HOME}/.bash_profile', '${HOME}/.bashrc', etc.).

Comment: I certainly don't see how you could unobtrusively attach to a running interactive shell process, run a command, and redirect it's output to a central file all without significantly affecting the existing user process.